# Kubernetes Ingress automated way to expose services

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Consider I have a domain name [www.saireddy.com](http://www.saireddy.com)

When ever a deployment, services deployed in kubernetes on dev namespace
eg servicename: nginx-svc, port: 80

I want an automated way to access this services on url
link [www.nginx-svc.dev.saireddy.com](http://www.nginx-svc.dev.saireddy.com)

in the same way if I deploy a different service on uat namespace
eg servicename: tomcat, port: 8080
then it should be accessible at
link [www.tomcat.uat.saireddy.com](http://www.tomcat.uat.saireddy.com)

Every time adding a ingress in yaml is a pain for dev cluster this will be super beneficial.
I wonder how kodekloud manages to do the same because when I deploy services in the lab I can instantly able to access the exposed url’s for that services with out any ingress files.

All the above with only a single ALB for all the namespaces in aws.
Is there any solution for these kind of situation.

Comment: You could write a controller that watches for new Service resources and then automatically creates corresponding Ingress resources.

Comment: wildcard domain and controller or even more simply a admission webhook with sideffects. But I would advice against automatic ingress creation. Its a security risk. You should carefully consider what you want to expose and if you even need to. And many ingress need customization. May it be stripping path prefix or using different backend protocol like FCGI.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a combination of an Ingress Controller and an automated tool to create DNS entries, such as [External DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns)

For example, you can install the [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) and External DNS in the cluster.

With this combination, as soon as the ingress controller "claims" the ingress, External DNS will create a DNS entry that maps the name in the ingress to the IP managed by the Ingress Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way would be to use wildcard DNS records.

You could have *.dev.my-domain.comm *.int, *.prod, ... all pointing to your kubernetes ingress controllers.

Then, kubernetes users can setup their own Ingresses, within those domains. No need to change your DNS configuration.

The External DNS suggested by @blender-fox also makes sense, if you can integrate with it. Although I would be careful when granting clusters privileges to change DNS records in my main domains ... It would be a god sent to any attacker trying to spoof your records ...